# Wordpress: Contact Form 7 Plugin Error: This email address does not belong to the same domain as the site

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

My wordpress installation was working fine all this time, until it upgraded contact form 7 to Version 4.4 now it has a configuration error.

**"Contact Form 7 Plugin Error: This email address does not belong to the same domain as the site"**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this, because it worked for me:

From: `[first-name] [last-name] <donotreply@your-site.com>`

Of course your-site.com is your domain and you might not have first and last names.

It's said that you to create a `@mysite.com` email with your host, maybe something like `do-not-reply@mysite.com.`

Hope that helps,

Comment: I just removed <[your-email]> from the email subject and added it to the message body in order to retain the senders email

Answer (score 2):

Change the current “your-email” to `admin@yourdomain.com` OR the email address that you receive messages from. It is also possible to create a new email address specifically for this purpose, you could name it “`no-reply@yoursite.com`”. You can drill-down more here.

[Contact Form 7 Issues](http://www.wiyre.com/solution-contact-form-7-issues-your-contact-form-has-a-configuration-issue/)